Dividing an object into two irregular parts using Blender
I have this object and I want to divide it into two irregular parts (with red line) as shown in the below figure. Bisect tool can't cut this object irregularly. can you help me how can I do this?
thanks a lot


Create a plane that will cut off the object, give a Boolean modifier to your object with the plane as Object:

Duplicate your object + plane. On the second version, flip the faces of your plane (AltN in Edit mode):

Apply the modifiers (keep a copy of your original object and plane though).
